# 2 Models. Feature distributons are same, though quality is lower

Tags: distributions, cross-validation, model-selection

The situation is following:

I took ML algorithm, say gradient boosting decision trees.

In october my data collector generated me  train data A. I did crossvalidation
and got **96**% of accuracy.

In november my data collector generated another train data B. 
train data A and B have equal characteristics:
Same shape, all the features has same distribution (tested with Kolmogorov and other tests), their PDFs are equal visually.
However, accuracy measured with crossval on set B is **79**%.

How can it happen? What fundamental properties of data besides feature distribution do affect here?

Answer (score 0):

Finaly, the reason was following:
I compared only marginal features distribution, however their joint
distribution has changed completely.